# Azure React App 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Facing issue with Azure App Service, when trying to deploy react app. I have tried other solutions of adding the web.config to my /src folder.

App: built using create-react-app

Index.js: `import "./web.config";`

web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration>   <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

Using the following github actions .yml file:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - fitrskills

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Node.js version
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.13.0'

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'fitrskills'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_xyz123 }}
        package: .`
```

Error: navigate to https://fitrskills.azurewebsites.net/ 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'

Comment: I had the exact same issue a few days ago. check this repo of mine, which has a working YAML for react apps - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/ReactJSRecipeApp

Comment: you can also check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872925/react-js-azure-devops-web-app-wont-run-but-files-are-present-in-server-and-no-er

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Need to set the yaml variable to package: 'build'

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me too