# React app deployed with Azure Devops gives "You do not have permission to view this directory or page"

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I managed to deploy my react app with an Azure CD pipeline on an Azure App Service. And the pipeline throws no error.
Unfortunately when I click browse on the Azure app service I get this message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I enabled advanced logging and here is what I get:
[image]

Here is my web.config file content:

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Any hint on how to solve this issue?[image]

Comment: I had a similar situation. try this post of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872925/react-js-azure-devops-web-app-wont-run-but-files-are-present-in-server-and-no-er . it has the full YAML and the same error that you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end, I managed to solved the issue this way: I removed the step that did the zip file in the pipeline and in the web config I left only the part with the React routes. Indeed, previously I directly deployed the zip file without unzipping it and it seems that this was causing the problem.

Comment: you see, you never posted your YAML file. So, i have no idea what you are talking about :) but glad the issue is solved.

Comment: @OuterSpace You can convert your workaround into an answer, it can help other community members who get the same issues more easily to find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to configure the following in Azure Web App Configuration:

1. index.js as a Default Document
2. change the virtual path to \site\wwwroot\build
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Adding \build to my path fixed my similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page

The root reason is that there is no default page in your Azure website. You can try to directly view the page with following url.

```
https://{siteanme}.azurewebsites.net/views/login.html
```

Or you could add the [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents) in the project root folder and set it as default page in appsetting on the Azure portal and save the setting.

> The default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL
> for a website.

[image]

In addition, you can check the IP restrictions or authentication settings on the Azure web application that may block you.

Check Web App > Authentication /Authorization and Web App > Networking > Access Restrictions

Here is a [blog](https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321) about deploying create-react-app on Microsoft Azure, you can refer to.

1. Created the production build by executing `npm run build` command. A
   `build` folder got generated in the solution with some meta data files
2. Once connected via the FTP client, copy the entire content of the
   `build` folder created earlier into the `/site/wwwroot/` folder on your
   Azure Website