# App Service deploy of NODE JS app fails with web.config error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am deploying a NODE JS app to an Azure App Service using Azure Devops pipelines, but it failes with the following error

```
##[error]Error: Failed to generate web.config. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_09902550774824137\web.config'
```

But in my deploy step I have the generate web.config step so I am not sure why its not working?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline definition and the step on how to generate web.config?

Comment: i would also suggest looking at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872925/react-js-azure-devops-web-app-wont-run-but-files-are-present-in-server-and-no-er I faced a similar issue and was able to solve it. i have even put full, working YAML files so you can compare and contrast.