# Node JS Deployment to Azure Web App Service ERROR - "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment

I've been following this tutorial on how to deploy a NodeJS app to Azure:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWdxkhajCg0&fbclid=IwAR10Q6x8PbqLDAZZzzMX9Nvp_jEGiN_Ts4V8XLJbzF6xreq6_MB_vsbIqx8

Firstly, I did everything exactly the same way as the author showed and it all worked. In the video, they're using Linux Web App Service. Since I have to get familiar with the Windows App Services (that's what I am required to learn and use for my job), I decided to deploy exactly same app to the Windows Web App service. However, instead of the home page, I only saw "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.".

I've already read bunch of solutions online, people suggest adding a web.config file, but it didn't help no matter what I added to that. The app is not supposed to limit any ip addresses/user groups as it's supposed to be a newly deployed app with no access restrictions (just as in the tutorial).

The only hint that I found out is that on Linux it works, on Windows it doesn't.

The app code is here:

https://github.com/Aitemir/MSP005

Comment: i had a similar issue which i posted earlier. look at it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872925/react-js-azure-devops-web-app-wont-run-but-files-are-present-in-server-and-no-er . the app is react, but the issue was node JS.

Comment: also, put your YAML file here if you are using devops.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Because you uploaded the code to `GitHub`, my answer will help you very well. Jay's solution should also be effective, but he uses `DevOps`. If you are interested, you can also study.

Using `Github` to deploy `web app` will be very convenient.

**Steps to solve my problem:**

1. Download your source code and upload it to my Github.

[image]

2. Create a web app.

[image]

3. Use continuous deployment.

[image]

4. Delete `.yml` file. Delete all file in this folder.

[image]

5. View deployment status.

[image]

[image]

When you follow my way, you will successfully deploy your application. You can also put the generated [`web.config file`](https://pastebin.pl/view/e3e649b7) in the current application in kudu, which should solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: For some reason this method never worked from me. It says "Failed to set up deployment".

Comment: @Aiti This information is prompted when github is selected for deployment in the portal, and I often encounter this prompt. Suggestions, 1. Try a few more times 2. Create a new webapp for testing 3. Raise a support ticket on portal.