# Azure App service and Angular SSR application

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an angular app with Server side rendering. And also, this `server.ts` has some simple APIs in it. I am trying to deploy it in Azure app service(with AD integration) but with no success. What could it be still missing?

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node dist/angular-app/server/main.js",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"dev:ssr": "ng run angular-app:serve-ssr",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/angular-app/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run angular-app:server:production",
"prerender": "ng run angular-app:prerender"
},
```

Error message when I access the Azure app service url:

[image]

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This problem is generally caused by the lack of `web.config`.**

For more details, you can check my answers in below posts.

[1. Azure Web App getting “You do not have permission to view this directory or page.” when launch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983932/azure-web-app-getting-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/63985336#63985336)

[2. Node JS Deployment to Azure Web App Service ERROR - “You do not have permission to view this directory or page.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071999/node-js-deployment-to-azure-web-app-service-error-you-do-not-have-permission/64095149#64095149)