# deployed my asp.net core react application in azure app services not showing anything

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I deployed my asp.net core react application created from VS2019 using VS2019 continuous delivery.
all succeeded till the creation of pipelines and deploying the app to azure app service.

but when I open the website, it won't show my landing page. no errors are thrown but no display of
any of my pages as well.

Comment: deployed how - classic or YAML? if you used YAML, then show us your YAML code.did you check KUDU console? are the files there under wwwroot. any errors on the browser console?

Comment: also, some general web troubleshooting steps available here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872925/react-js-azure-devops-web-app-wont-run-but-files-are-present-in-server-and-no-er

Comment: i deployed directly from VS2019. by creating a continuous deployment configuration using the publish option

Comment: sorry man, unless you can try the steps in the linked question above, cannot help you further. some of the steps apply to you. try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy web app to Azure and login `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net`, then the page still shows Microsoft page instead you owner page. You need check the default document, please ensure that the default page is listed in here.

Steps: login azure portal->App Service->configuration->Default documents

In Azure Web Apps, the default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. Refer [File structure on azure](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure) to know more about the files and directories on Azure Web App.

[image]